# Unable to use date-picker in ui.bootstrap. Am i defining my app and controller correctly?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, ui.bootstrap

trying to add a date picker to my app : 
defining an app like this : (app.js)
`var app = angular.module("scplApp",['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);`

defining controller like this: (date-picker.js)
    app.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {...}]);

getting this error:
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider

what am i missing here?? (new to ui design)

Comment: could you share the complete stack error

Comment: Did you load all required JavaScript libraries? Please provide a plunker with your setup.

Comment: i was using angular 1.3.14 earlier......just changed that to 1.4.7 and it worked......sorry i didn't post that code here....:)

Comment: how can i set the minDate to the first of the month?
 var date = new Date();
  $scope.minDate = date.setDate(new Date(date.getYear(),date.getMonth(),1));
tried this.